# Fragment savedInstanceState not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-savedstate

I have several fragments here and there's this one fragment where I want to save its state when I get back to it. I tried doing it in a testfragment where, when I click the button, the textview text will change to "test1"(The default text of the textview is "New Text"). So the textview changes the text, but when I move into another fragment and get back to it (`HomeFragment`), the textview is going to its default state text ("New Text"). So I think the `savedInstanceState` is not working because if it does, it should have "test1" when I get back to the fragment. Here's my code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public Button button;
    public TextView txt_test;
    public String data_test;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){

        }
        else{
            data_test = savedInstanceState.getString("txt_test");
            txt_test = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt_test.setText(data_test);
        }
        button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);
        txt_test = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt_test.setText("test1");

            }
        });
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("txt_test",data_test);
    }

}
```

Comment: `onActivityCreated` runs **after** `onCreateView`, so you overwrite the text in the textview.

Comment: Thank you for noticing my post, @EpicPandaForce. So I should put onActivityCreated first then OnCreateView. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: no, you should move the `if(savedInstance == null)` stuff into the `onActivityCreated` method (actually, you should just move the whole thing over to `onViewCreated()`)

Comment: Hello, @EpicPandaForce. I tried your suggestion, but it's still not working. It still doesnt remain the text("test1") whenever i go to another fragment or even change the orientation of the app. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Hello, Guys, Just to let you know, It's still not working, I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    Button button;
    TextView txt_test;
    String data_test;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        txt_test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt_test.setText("test1");
            }
        });

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            data_test = savedInstanceState.getString("txt_test");
            txt_test.setText(data_test);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("txt_test",data_test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, @EpicPandaForce. Thank you for your answer, I tried your answer, I tested it by changing the orientation. It works! But, when I go to another fragment(FragmentB)then get back to this fragment(FragmentA). The text is gone. Any ideas why?

Comment: You go back with pressing Back, and the other fragment is added to the backstack,  right? It should work on back too....

Comment: Hello, @EpicPandaForce. No, I'm afraid not. I'm using a navigation drawer. So for example, I open navigation drawer, I go to fragment a, press the button then the textview's text changes. Then I open navigation drawer, i go to fragment B. Then, I open navigation drawer, then i go to fragment A.

Comment: If you replace the fragment without putting it in backstack, its state (and saved instance state) will be cleared along with the fragment.

Comment: I believe I didn't do anything to put it in backstack since I never tried it before. can you please tell me more further about it? and if possible, update your answer along with it's sample? just to let you know, I have a navigation drawer, also have the method onNavigationItemSelected, the fragment changes based on it.

Comment: I hope you can tell me more about it and the backstack with some provided code samples or just update your answer. it's kind of late in my time, I'll try your updated answer as soon as possible, I hope you can help me with this. i don't know what to do anymore. i tried searching for answers but their answers are all HACK and many comments says that it's a bad practice so I didnt do it. i hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to manage the state in the container activity, unfortunately.